# Where to act on changed child properties in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm confused, and I have searched a lot for the answer to this (seemingly) basic question.

I'm learning React, and I have a rather common component hierarchy with one top component (lets call it App) which contains a number of subcomponents (a grid, a graph, a table etc).

They all show information regarding one product.

Now when I select a row in the grid, I want to inform the other subcomponents about the change. App therefore passes a callback method

```
onSelectedProduct={this.onSelectedProduct}
```

to the grid. This gets called OK. In this App method I set the state:

```
onSelectedProduct(product) {
  this.setState({ product: product });
}
```

In its render(), App has declared another subcomponent:

```
<ProductGraph product={this.state.product} />
```

Since ProductGraph needs to fetch some data asynchronously "to-be-rendered" later, where should I catch this property change??

The old "componentWillReceiveProps" sounded like the proper place, but will be deprecated and should not be used, I understand.

I have also tried shouldComponentUpdate, getDerivedStateFromProps and even to catch it in render, but they all have downsides and eventually lead to horrible code.

Somewhere, somehow, I should be able to detect that props.product !== state.product and issue an async load call for the data...

When the async method I call returns with the data, it will set the state and render itself.

So where is the optimal place to catch changed properties?

I have read a lot about the React Lifecycle but I just can't seem to find this basic information. Am I stupid or maybe blind? Or have I got this completely wrong somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for `componentDidUpdate()` the lifecycle method that triggers when a component receives new props or has an updated state.

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate

In your ProductGraph component, you would do something like:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps){
   if(this.props.product !== prevProps.product){
      fetch(`myApi/${this.props.product}`)
         .then(res => res.json())
         .then(data => this.setState({ data: data })) <-- identify what you need from object
         .catch((errors) => {
             console.log(errors)
         })
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! When reading the docs I see that I misunderstood the meaning of that method. I'm also using websockets, so the passing of the socket to the subcomponent was also part of the problem but your answer helped me fix it! Great that one can still ask dumb questions on SO without beeing flamed!

Comment: That's awesome @PeterAndersson! Your question was fine haha. I've asked much worse xD